# Dependency Of Spring boot Microservice

Tags: spring-boot, maven, github, microservices, pom.xml

We have a GIT Repository which contains multiple microservices (around 120 microservices). I would like to know is there a process available to check all the poms in the repository to see if the pom contains a specific dependency jar . For example there is a microservice A and I wanted to know if there is a dependency for jar(woodstox-core) available in the pom without manually opening the POM and checking it.

Since there are around 120 microservices analysing each pom manually for the dependency would be very time consuming .  Also the same excercise needs to be repeated for other git repositories as well.

Any help on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the repo has a root parent pom file then this problem is easy. You can just run "mvn dependency:tree" from the root and this will list off all the dependencies in the children services.

If this is not the case, and each service is built as a stand alone service (in the eyes of maven). You will need to write a small script which will iterate over all the children services/folders in the root git repo and run the "mvn dependency:tree". If you are doing this in a bash script you can pipe all the output of the tree command to append to a central file and the just search one central location once you are done.